# Android AdView not showing

Tags: android, admob, ads, adview

I'm having issues with ADs in my Android App.
Sometimes the AD is not shown, probably depending on the DPI or Size of the screen's device.

In my code, I implemented a check to set View.GONE in case the AD fails to load, but despite that on some devices I still have **blank spaces** where it's supposed to be the AD

For example, here one of my ADs

```
if(holder.nativeExpressAdView != null) {
            AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .build();
            holder.nativeExpressAdView.loadAd(request);
            Utilities.setAdListenerNative(holder.nativeExpressAdView);
        }
```

---

```
//ADs listener to remove view if it fails load
    //NATIVE ADS
    public static void setAdListenerNative(final NativeExpressAdView nativeExpressAdView) {
        nativeExpressAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(i);
                nativeExpressAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: can you also add logs? Filter on Ads

Comment: I had the same problem . The ad was showing when i added the device id to builder . Try to add device id to builder . But without  it giving me the error code of Server Error. Check the Error code you are gettig in error response . I finally finished with using big size banner ad except native

Answer (score 0):

First show me your log

Second Dont use "Gone" because this will change the position of the adView if you are using other sizes of Android scale you will see that.

Third use a debugger.

Use "`invisible`"